# Deploying driver without installer

Tags: active-directory, deployment, drivers

I would like to know if there is any way to deploy a driver via Active Directory that does not have an installer. I have a bunch of *.dll files and the necessary cat and inf files. But they are not packaged in any kind of installer.

I have looked into driver stores and maybe copying the files to a custom search directory.

I am by no means an expert or experienced with active directory. But I would like to know if this is at all possible before I proceed investigating this further. Unfortunately searching does not yield to much relevant results.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Duplicate? https://serverfault.com/questions/592045/update-a-network-driver-through-gpo-ad
This will likely be done through a GPO, never done it myself, but google pointed me to this site that's helped me in the past: https://deployhappiness.com/automating-hardware-driver-installation-on-windows-7-and-above/

Comment: Thank you very much. The links you provided looks very promising. I will report back here when I find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The links provided by user [gregg](https://serverfault.com/users/131761/gregg) helped me a lot. In the end I went with a small script that copies over the driver files to the local machine and then run `pnputil -i -a {path}/{to}/driver.inf`.

The howto guide at [deployhappiness](https://deployhappiness.com/automating-hardware-driver-installation-on-windows-7-and-above/) is very useful and would be a very good solution. I tested the custom drive store directory with a registry entry and all worked as expected.